# Send Json data and redirect using Jquery and node js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, redirect

I have the following page as shown below:[image]

When I click on the edit button, I want the send the id of button to my node JS server which will redirect me to the following webpage:
[image]

And also my Node JS server will send back the JSON data to fill up the form in the following page. The problem I am facing is that whenever I click the button, my page is not redirected.
The following jquery code sends an ajax call:

```
$("#viewAllContest button").click(function () {
//console.log($(this).attr('id'));
var id = $(this).attr('id');
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/contests/redirectContest',
    data: JSON.stringify({id:id}),
    success: function(data) { console.log('success')},
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json'
    });
});
```

Then my routes in Node JS app receives the request and should redirect the page:

```
router.post('/redirectContest',function (req,res) {
var id = req.body.id;
console.log(id);
res.redirect('/contests/viewContest');});
```

I have even added `return res.redirect('/contests/viewContest');` but it does not redirect my webpage. The code to render viewContest is:

```
router.get('/viewContest',ensureAuthenticated,function (req,res) {

res.render('viewContest');});
```

I would be grateful if someone can guide me as to where I am going wrong here.

Comment: Are you getting `id` in `redirectContest`?

Comment: Yes i am receiving the id in redirectContest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to modify the below route-

```
router.post('/redirectContest',function (req,res) {
var id = req.body.id;
console.log(id);
//remove the redirect code
//res.redirect('/contests/viewContest');});
//Now send the json response 
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
res.send(JSON.stringify({ url: '/contests/viewContest' }));
```

Now modify your ajax code as below-

```
$("#viewAllContest button").click(function () {
//console.log($(this).attr('id'));
var id = $(this).attr('id');
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/contests/redirectContest',
    data: JSON.stringify({id:id}),
    success: function(data) { window.location.href=data.url;},
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json'
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you that was helpful! Also do you by any chance know why I am getting two id's when i click the first button but i get only one when I click the second button when I console log it in redirect route function. I am getting the following console log. { id: 'Bqk6QzB7' }
{ id: 'GL55DSMd' }
{ id: 'GL55DSMd' }

Comment: You also have to send back `data` of the `selected record` to fill it in the `viewContest` page.

Comment: @MUT Yes, I know about that, I have different method to fill viewContest page. What I am confused is when I click the first edit button in the table. Its sending me two repeat ID's to my node js server instead of just one.